# Access to System Audio on Mac

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, equalizer

For a some-what small (at least hopefully) project, I am hoping to gain access to the current audio being played through the "main line" (i.e. what is heard through the speakers.)  Specifically, I'd like to create a visual equalizer of the audio currently being played.  I do not wish to capture or "tamper" with the audio in any way, just run a little analysis on it.  That being said, I'd imagine access to such information is not handed out nicely in a high-level API.

I noticed a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188023/capture-sound-output-on-mac)  which is concerned with looking at system sound.  The accepted answer points to looking into Soundflower's source code.  I am not completely adverse to doing this but I'd like to ensure there isn't a simpler way before I got into it (especially because I have no real audio programming experience, especially at the system level.)

Any input is very much appreciated,

--Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this on OS X.  You really have to do this from a kext, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, was afraid of that.  Thanks for your help!